# Express.js: Serving path provided by user

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, server, filesystems

So everyone is familiar with serving static files from a hard-coded path such as `/public`. How do I do that but serve files from a `path` provided as input from the user?

**Use case:** This is a **local** server and so after running the server, the user selects which folder to serve so that it can be available across the local network for access. I'm looking to create a video streaming API which will play videos served on the `path` selected by the user.

Currently, I list the items in the `path` like so:

```
const Promise = require('bluebird');
const path = require('path')
const fs = Promise.promisifyAll(require('fs'));

async listDir(dir) {
    const list = [];
    const dirItems = await fs.readdirAsync(dir); // get all items in the directory

    for (const item of dirItems) {
      const absPath = path.join(dir, item);
      const stat = await fs.lstatAsync(absPath);
      const isFile = stat.isFile(); // check if item is a file
      list.push({ name: item, isFile }); // return item name and isFile boolean
    }

    return list;
  }
```

Do I then just do pattern-matching in another route to return whichever file is asked for inside the `dir`?

Am I going about this the right way? Any suggestion/answer is appreciated.

Comment: You create a route that takes as a parameter (either encoded in the URL as a query parameter or in the body of a form post) the desired path.  The code for that route, then fetches the file at that path and serves it back to the user.  One route can be coded to serve any requested path.  And, I hope you understand the security ramifications of letting the user tell you what part of the server's hard drive they want to see.

Comment: To avoid having to store state for the user about which folder is the "current" folder, then why not just have the user deal in full paths.  Then, your route will get a request for a full path and you won't have to have previously kept per-user state on which folder is the current folder.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. I'm thinking of something along the lines of an FTP server or the Jupyter notebook. Only the host should be able to set the path to be served. And the users within the network can access the items within the path.

Comment: Well, now I'm hopelessly confused.  That comment completely conflicts with what your question says, both in the title and in the first sentence of the question where you say the user is providing the path.

Comment: If the server is just offering things for the user to choose, then you just have to create a unique URL that represents any given resource you're allowing the user to choose.  How you do that is entirely up to you.  When the user clicks on that URL, you need a route that handles that URL.  Probably you create one common route and the resource is specified in some sort of URL parameter so you can do all this from one route.  That one route looks at the parameter, turns it into a reference to the actual resource and serves it.

Comment: Ah, my bad. The user setting the path will still be accessing the API to set it. It's just that the API won't be available for non-"localhost" users.

Comment: You're suggesting the pattern-matching solution mentioned above then? So we won't be actually using Express' `express.static` to serve the files, but rather manually define endpoints (in our case, one) for retrieving the files?

Comment: `express.static()` is likely not appropriate here as it generally wants the resource locations to be established at server startup time.  And, you should be able to do all this from one route anyway.  I never understood what you meant by a pattern matching algorithm so I don't know what that is.  At some point you generate a web page that shows the user a list of resources.  Each resource has a URL associated with in in that web page.  You create a route that can process anyone of those URLs and create the desired result.

Comment: How you match a URL with a resource is a design question and there are lots of possible ways to do it.  The simplest and stateless way would be to encode a path in the resource URL, but there are many considerations that go into deciding on the best strategy and those considerations often involve understanding a bigger picture or your app (and its security ramifications) than you have explained here.